# Swift protocol isn't triggering Objective C protocol method

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, protocols, viewcontroller

I have a Swift view controller that defines a protocol that should be followed in an Objective-C view controller:

**ChildViewController.swift**

```
@objc public protocol ChildViewControllerDelegate {
    func closeChild();
}

@objc public class ChildViewController: UIViewController{

    var delegate: ChildViewControllerDelegate?

    @IBAction func childCloseButton(sender: UIButton) {
       delegate?.closeChild()
    }

}
```

**MainViewController.m**

```
@interface MainViewController () <ChildViewControllerDelegate>

@end

@implementation MainViewController
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    // creating frame for child and placing it on the bottom of the screen
        CGFloat screenWidth = [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.width;
        CGFloat screenHeight = [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.height;
        CGFloat yOffset = self.view.frame.origin.y;
        CGFloat childHeight = (8/15) * screenWidth;
        CGRect child = CGRectMake(0, screenHeight - yOffset - childHeight, screenWidth, childHeight);

        // adding storyboard 
        UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"child" bundle:nil];
        ChildViewController *childVC = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"childViewController"];
        childVC.view.frame = childBox;
        [self addChildViewController: childVC];
        [self.view addSubview:childVC.view];
}

- (void) closeChild {
    NSLog(@"Why doesn't this get trigger???");
}

@end
```

When I click the "childCloseButton" on the UI, the "closeChild" method in MainViewController.m doesn't seem to get called.  Stepping through the debugger, I discovered the "delegate" property ChildViewController.swift is set to nil but I don't understand why.  Can somebody tell me what I'm missing?

Comment: post the code where you have added your child view controller=

Comment: Where did you set the delegate?

Comment: You haven't set the delegate property, thats why its nil and not getting triggered

Comment: Can you show me where I would set the delegate property?  I thought it was being set in the first line of class ChildViewController's body.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first line in `ChildViewController`'s body is creating an optional property. This is nil until set with something. There is nothing unique here to do with delegates, this is just simply object oriented programming.

In the same way to set the frame property of `childVC` later on in `MainViewController`, you need to also set the delegate to be this instance of `MainViewController`.

e.g.

```
ChildViewController *childVC = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"childViewController"];
childVC.view.frame = childBox;
childVC.delegate = self
```

Comment: Duh!!  Thanks, Simon!